# Parameter express can't be passed with require

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parameter-passing, require

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use("/", require("./routers.js")(app));

app.listen(3000);
```

router.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  console.log(app);
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json(5);
  });
};
```

The error given by the Console is:  " TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got an undefined "

I don't understand why I can't pass the express app(app.js) through routers( in this way I don't redeclare the express and app variable in router.js ).

Comment: Is the second code block routers.js? If so, please [edit] your question and label it. While you're at it, change the reference in your last sentence to routers.js to match the code (or change both to router.js). Consistency and spelling matters greatly in programming.

Comment: btw I resolved the issue returning in router.js the app variable. So in router.js at the end of module.exports I simply write:    return app. But It would be nice if you know other methods to resolve the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass app to routes better to create a new router and pass to the app.

router.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json(5);
});
module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
app.use("/", require("./routers.js"));
```

As you mention in the comment, you don't have to add an inside app.use

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json(5);
  });
};

// app.js
require("./routers.js")(app);
```

Comment: my goal is to don't instantiate a new express variable. That's why I have passed express as a parameter in app.js. I don't if it is possible to do... and in the first answer to my question, @joseluis fernandez mateo says to use exports.method = ... but this isn't so much scalable as I've done. :(

Comment: @antoniosalzano I've update my answer do check

Answer (score 0):

The use method of Express needs a callback of three parameters, not the app itself, so you need something like this:

In routes.js

```
exports.doSomeThing = function(req, res, next){
    console.log("Called endpoint");
    res.send("Called endpoint");
}
```

In your index.js

```
const Express = require("express");
const app = Express();
const routes = require("./routes");

app.use("/", routes.doSomeThing);

app.listen(3030, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3030");
});
```

This approach doesn't need to include the express router but this may not be adecuate for big scale projects I recommend you to read express router documentation:

https://expressjs.com/es/guide/routing.html#express-router